# Gtk# Embed TextView in ToolBar

Tags: c#, gtk#

Is there any way to embed a TextView widget in a ToolBar? I am using Gtk# with C# on mono in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this for a project and was able to accomplish by manually setting the Width and Height Request. Putting the TextView in a HBox (or similar) also works.

```
    Toolbar _toolBar = new Toolbar();

    TextView t = new TextView();
    t.WidthRequest = 200;
    t.HeightRequest = 20;
    _toolBar.Add(t);

    t.Buffer.Text = "Hello World!";
    t.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. As it turned out, it seems easier just to add an Entry than a TextView, but it is good to know that I can do that.